# How to use Apache Flink with lookup data?

Tags: apache-flink

.

Hi,

using Apache Flink 1.8. I have a stream of records coming in from Kafka as JSON and filtering them and that all works fine.

Now, I would like to enrich the data from Kafka with a look up value from a database table.

Is that just a case of creating 2 streams, loading the table in the 2nd stream and then joining the data?

The database table does get updated but not frequently and I would like to avoid looking up the DB on every record that comes through the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink has state, which you could take advantage of here. I've done something similar, where I took a daily query from my lookup table (in my case it was a bulk webservice call) and through the results into a kafka topic. This kafka topic was being consumed by the same service flink job as that needed the data for lookups. Both topics were keyed by the same value, but I used the lookup topic to store data into a keyed state, and when processing the other topic, I'd pull the data back out of state.

I had some additional logic to check if there was NO state yet for a given key. If that was the case, I'd make an async request to the webservice. You may not need to do that however.

The caveat here is that I had memory for state management, and my lookup table was only about 30-million records, about 100 gigs spread across 45 slots on 15 nodes.

[In answer to question in comments]
Sorry, but my answer was too long, so had to edit my post:

I had a python job that loaded the data via a bulk REST call (yours could just do a data lookup). It then transformed the data into the correct format and dumped it into Kafka. Then my flink flow had two sources, one was the 'real data' topic, the other was the 'lookup data' topic.  Data coming from the lookup data topic was stored in state (I used a ValueState because each key mapped to a single possible value, but there are [other state types](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html).  I also had a 24 hour expiration time for each entry, but that was my usecase.

The trick is that the same operation that stores the value in state from the lookup topic, has to be the operation that pulls the value back out of state from the 'real' topic. This is because flink state (even keyed states) are tied to the operator that created them.

Comment: My lookup table is not that big maybe a few hundred rows. But what did you use to load the data a separate stream?

Comment: @user432024 I updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: Cool. I'll accept your answer. I actually had a similar idea by loading into Apache Ignite since I'm already using it... There is also: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/operators/asyncio.html

Comment: My experience with async processes in flink are not positive. Internally it seems to use an Executor service, and if the flow of data gets too high, the executor's task queue gets full. Adding the task queue then blocks until there is space in the queue, which creates back-pressure.  For me, this led to increasing lag and eventually dropped messages. In my experience, avoid async processes, unless the number of requests can be kept to a bare minimum.

Comment: Ok so in my case. I will have a job loading to Apache Ignite and I will have a FlatMap that does a lookup to Ignite and enriches the data that way. Example: https://github.com/dataArtisans/yahoo-streaming-benchmark/blob/master/flink-benchmarks/src/main/java/flink/benchmark/AdvertisingTopologyNative.java#L119

Comment: Cool. I know very little about Ignite at this point. Something I've been meaning to look more into.

Comment: What about this JDBCInputFormat? It's scarcely documented.

Comment: Hi @zacrioca, what you actually stored in ValueState? I mean what type?
You wrote that it was data from lookup topic which was stored there, but I guess you had to use a List or Map actually to store all the records. So if you stored Collection in your ValueState  that means that the whole collection was serialized/deserialized on each interaction with that state.